# Spring Data Rest Make an Entity Read Only by Default

Tags: jackson, spring-data-rest

I have an API exposed via Spring Data Rest which, for the most part, is read-only but which allows for updating of some properties via PATCH requests.

Is there any (I'm supposing Jackson) configuration at a global level that would essentially make an entity read only unless specific properties were annotated in some way.

I am familiar with the`@JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)` Jackson annotation however would like to avoid having to annotate all read-only properties.

For example, given the class below only the field explicitly annotated would be writable. All other fields would be readable by default:

```
public class Thing{

    private String fieldOne;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    private String fieldTwo;

    private String fieldThree;

    // a lot of other properties
}
```

Failing any global configuration, is there anything that can be applied at the class level?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any way to globally set all attributes in a class to read only.  Since version 2.6+ of FaserXML you can use the following annotation to at least defined the set of properties you would ignore and only allow for serialization.  The following annotation would be used at the class level:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value={ "fieldOne", "fieldThree"}, allowGetters=true)
```

It is not exactly what you are looking for, but arguably makes coding a little easier.